# Strange code timing behavior in Java

Tags: java

In the following code:

```
long startingTime = System.nanoTime();
int max = (int) Math.pow(2, 19);
for(int i = 0; i < max; ){
    i++;
}
long timePass = System.nanoTime() - startingTime;
System.out.println("Time pass " + timePass / 1000000F);
```

I am trying to calculate how much time it take to perform simple actions on my machine.

All the calculations up to the power of 19 increase the time it takes to run this code, but when I went above 19(up to max int value 31) I was amazed to discover that it have no effect on the time it takes.
It always shows 5 milliseconds on my machine!!!

How can this be?

Comment: Math.pow is not only expensive but can have rounding errors. Try `1 << 19` which is the same as `(int) Math.pow(2, 19)` except more efficient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have just witnessed HotSpot optimizing your entire loop to oblivion. It's **smart**. You need to do some real action inside the loop. I recommend introducing an `int` accumulator var and doing some bitwise operations on it, and finally **printing** the result to ensure it's needed after the loop.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: Very nice find, @JoachimSauer.

Comment: Making the counter `static` can prevent some optimisation and stop the loop being reduced to nothing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think I already saw HotSpot being smart enough to just **add** `N` directly to the counter, instead of incrementing it `N` times!

Comment: It can do that, but in this case it may detect that `i` is not used after the loop and discard it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey My comment is in response to your suggestion with `static`. It won't discard `i` in that case, but it may still assign the end result directly to it.

Comment: Good point, I have just tested it and it appears it does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

On the HotSpot JVM, `-XX:CompileThreshold=10000` by default.  This means a loop which iterates 10K times can trigger the whole method to be optimised.  In your case you are timing how long it take to detect and compile (in the background) your method.

Comment: It is fun to notice also that, if we can assume OP is running the whole thing in a single method. HotSpot actually replaces the method's code in the middle of its execution, transfering the complete state from the interpreted to the compiled version!

Comment: Something JRocket doesn't do btw. This means that your first main() will never be optimised in JRocket.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: when I read up on some HotSpot teachniques I came accross "deoptimization" which actually does the reverse! That's even more fun. (That's necessary if a assumption made about the code later gets invalidated, such as the VM "knowing" that there's only a single class involved and later a second class in the same hierarchy gets loaded).

Comment: I believe it will also deoptimise if it assume a condition is always false and it later becomes true (visa-versa) e.g. turning assertions on.

Answer (score 0):

use another System.nanoTime() in the loop. no  one can optimize this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < max; ){
i++;
dummy+=System.nanoTime();
}
```

dont forget to do:

```
System.out.println(dummy);
```

after the loop. ensures non-optimization

Comment: Isn't the `nanoTime()` call quite costly compared to, say, `acc |= i`?  You'll basically be measuring the performance of `nanoTime()` this way.

Comment: if you add 40 or 200 lines of i++;i++;i++; you can dwarf     System.nanoTime()

Comment: also if you get the time of nanotimed-loop, you can use this as an offset value to subtract from other test which include nanotime. you will need lots of samplings to get a proper result